# Como pegar todas as páginas de uma API e mostrar todos os dados de uma vez só na tela usando react hooks?

Tags: api, react, react-hooks

Oi, estou estudando react hooks e como base estou usando uma API do Rick and Morty para mostrar os personagens na tela https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/
Porém,só mostra vinte personagens por página e tem no total 26 páginas. Eu queria mostrar todos os 493 personagens na tela de uma vez só. Eu li a documentação, porém, não há uma query específica para isso. Então eu tentei fazer um for que passasse por todas páginas. No momento, quando o código é executado ele vai mostrando todos os personagens, mas no fim do loop ficam apenas os últimos 20 personagens da última página na tela. Vocês podem ver o resultado aqui https://project-soctest.herokuapp.com/

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { CardGrid, Card } from './tableStyled.js';
import Navbar from '../Navbar/Navbar.js';
import api from '../../services/api.js';

const Table = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [numPages] = useState([26]);

   useEffect(() => {
     async function loadData() {
       for(var i = 0; i < numPages; i++){
         const apiResponse = await api.get(`?page=` + i);
         setCharacters(apiResponse.data.results);
      } 
    }
   loadData();
   }, [numPages]); 

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar/>
       <CardGrid>
         {characters.map(character => (
        <Card key={character.id}>
          <img src={character.image} alt={character.name} />
          <section>
            <header>
              <h3>
                <span>{character.id}</span> {character.name}
              </h3>
              <h4>
                <span>{character.species} - {character.status}</span>
              </h4>
              <h4>
                <span>{character.origin.name}</span>
              </h4>
            </header>
          </section>
        </Card>
    ))};
  </CardGrid>
</div>
);
};

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz o "for" para fazer o loop e consultar as outras páginas da API, você guarda o resultado dentro do state "characters", então ele sempre apaga o valor anterior e grava apenas a chamada atual, por isso que você sempre tem no state o resultado da última página.

Para preservar os valores existentes e adicionar novos, você precisa utilizar o spread operator. O seu "setCharacters" ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
setCharacters(prevState => {
    return { ...prevState, apiResponse.data.results}
});
```

A função loadData ficaria assim:

```
async function loadData() {
   for(var i = 0; i < numPages; i++){
    const apiResponse = await api.get(`?page=` + i);
    setCharacters(prevState => {
        return { ...prevState, apiResponse.data.results}
    });
}
```